# Div inside anchor bug

Tags: css, html

So I created a 'div' tag and tried to put it inside an 'a' tag. From what I understood from searching about this topic is that you can do this in html5, but you couldn't do it in html4.
But there is a bug when I open the html file in my browser. Not only is the 'div' clickable, but also all the space right of it.
Here is my html code:

```
    <a href="#"><div id="div1"></div></a>
```

and my css:

```
    #div1 {
            width:250px;
            height:200px;
            background:linear-gradient(orange,red);
    }
```

Do you know why this happens? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are block level elements by default and take up 100% width of their parent element. Change that to inline-block instead:

```css
#div1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(orange, red);
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div id="div1"></div>
</a>
```